# Access system tables in calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

Is there a way to access system tables in a SSAS cube calcuation?

For example the following query can be executed on a SSAS cube to return a last processed date:

```
SELECT LAST_DATA_UPDATE FROM $System.MDSCHEMA_CUBES WHERE CUBE_NAME = 'Cube'
```

How would one access this information in a calculation?

**Background:** We were using ASSP before (a third party sproc) to get the last cube processed date. Recently, this sproc threw an exception on one of our cubes and caused SSAS to go down. Using the above line of MDX did not have this behavior. I would rather not have our cube depend on third party code so I am looking for a way to access LAST_DATA_UPDATE in a calc for a specific cube name.

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? the code posted is not a SSA cube calculation

Comment: How does that deserve a downvote? I don't think the legitimacy of my question depends on the options I have tried. That query is an example of accessing system tables, I never claimed it was a calculation.

Comment: to cite from the title of the downwote: "This question does not show any research effort" - but this is only my opinion, other users will upvote it, if they find it a good question

Answer (score 1):

I usually include a detached Dimension in my cubes e.g. ".Cube Information" which includes attributes like this.  Other useful attributes could expose the currency of the data e.g. when did the last underlying ETL process complete, or the release/build of your cube.

I feed this "Cube Information" dimension from a SQL view which returns a single row with whatever data is needed - you could use your SELECT statement.  It also needs to return a Key column with a fixed value e.g. 1.

By "detached" I mean the "Cube Information" dimension has no entries in the Cube Dimension Relationship tab.

In the cube Calculation script, I assign the DEFAULT_MEMBER property for that dimension to the fixed Key value from the SSAS view.

Any client tool can then access those Dimension attributes.